# Redirect URL goes back to login instead of Home

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, auth0

I am using Flutter for frontend, and using the Auth0 verification SSO
This is my command for the redirect url

```
 Future<void> _login(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await auth0.loginWithRedirect(
        redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/*', // Update to the correct redirect URL
      );
      print('Authentication successful');

      // After successful authentication, navigate to HomeScreen
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
      );

      // Since the redirect will be handled by Auth0, there's no need to manually navigate here
    } catch (e) {
      print('Authentication error: $e');
    }
  }
```

In my Application URls in Auth0, I have declared callback URL to be this:
http://localhost:3000/*
After, I have specified in the login function above to redirect to HomeScreen, How do I fix this?